# Rails Many to many Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This may be simple but I was not sure if this is possible. The question is about the `group.rb` model if it is possible to `have_many` of a model that does not exist if it is through another model. Thanks for the help.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_groups
  has_many :groups
end

# app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_groups
  has_many :admins, through: :admin_groups
end

# app/models/admin_group.rb
class AdminGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*, this is totally valid.

Refer to the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer an associated model by name of your choice and use 'class_name' option to relate that reference name with real model as shown in your own code, and yes you can have (has_many, through) association with a model on just reference name while using 'class_name' option.

Follow these 2 links @

[guide1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

[guide2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference)